# Rails - Delayed Job - Sending an email for a deleted object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have an issue where I'm using DelayedJob to send out emails, using the .delay method call for deleted objects.  I have an Observer that checks for after_destroy and it kicks off a delayed email, but I'm getting

Delayed::DeserializationError

I know I'm getting this error cause the Record is not found but is there a way to bypass this to just send the email with the information in the delayed_jobs table and not look up the object in the database?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is wrap up the parts of your object in another object (before you delete it) and then call `.delay` on that:

```
notifier = WhatEver.new(self)
notifier.delay.send_email
```

Wrap something like that in a `before_destroy` callback on the thing you're destroying. The `WhatEver` class just pulls the relevant bits of information out of the object, stores those bits in instance variables, and then `WhatEver#send_email` builds and sends the email based on the information it extracted.

Doing things this way breaks the connection between the email and the (soon to be) dead object and should avoid the `DeserializationError`.

Comment: thanks should have used the before_destroy and didn't that fixed it.